# Spring Boot bean auto-configuration order

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have a package, class A in the package is annotated with `@Configuration` and `ConditionalOnBean(B.class)`, and it is loaded by `spring.factories`;

In other package's spring bean xml, there is a factory Bean C, and it autowires a bean B;

When I started the server, I found bean B and C, but there is no bean A registered.

The debug log shows that bean A negative matched, but spring found Bean B, the log just like:

```
[DEBUG] 20180615 17:19:23.200 [localhost-startStop-1] ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader - Registered bean definition for imported class 'A'
[DEBUG] 20180615 17:19:23.525 [localhost-startStop-1] ConfigurationClassEnhancer - Successfully enhanced A; enhanced class name is: A$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$590152cc
[DEBUG] 20180615 17:19:23.525 [localhost-startStop-1] ConfigurationClassPostProcessor - Replacing bean definition 'A' existing class 'A' with enhanced class 'A$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$590152cc'
[DEBUG] 20180615 17:19:23.586 [localhost-startStop-1] GenericScope - Generating bean factory id from names: [A]
[DEBUG] 20180615 17:20:11.825 [localhost-startStop-1] BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping - Rejected bean name 'A': no URL paths identified
[DEBUG] 20180615 17:20:13.574 [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'A'
[DEBUG] 20180615 17:20:13.574 [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating instance of bean 'A'
[DEBUG] 20180615 17:20:13.574 [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory - Eagerly caching bean 'A' to allow for resolving potential circular references
[DEBUG] 20180615 17:20:13.609 [localhost-startStop-1] DefaultListableBeanFactory - Finished creating instance of bean 'A'
report
A:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: B; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: B; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'defaultB' (OnBeanCondition)
```

I want to know:

1. the order springboot registers beans;
2. why the report show "did not find any bean" and "found bean" the same time?